# zk framework: how to load zul pages from WEB-INF under directory zul

Tags: java, zk, zul

I am using zk framework 6.
I am trying to put my zul pages in /WEB-INF/zul directory.
My index.zul file forwards the request to /WEB-INF/zul/login.zul which has a composer LoginComposer. 
But when I am on login page I want to redirect the user to another page e.g. home.zul. But I am getting 404 error.

Both login.zul and home.zul are in zul directory along with their respective composers.

in loginComposer.java i have the following code to redirect to the home page which is called on a button click.

```
 Execution exec = Executions.getCurrent();
                HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)exec.getNativeResponse();
                response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/WEB-INF/zul/home.zul")); //assume there is /login
                exec.setVoided(true);
```

I created the project as a zk project from eclipse and i made no changes to web.xml.

please guide me how can i go from here.

Thank in advance.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>abc</display-name>
  <listener>
    <description>
    Used to cleanup when a session is destroyed</description>
    <display-name>ZK Session cleaner</display-name>
    <listener-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.HttpSessionListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description>
    The ZK loader for ZUML pages</description>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.ui.http.DHtmlLayoutServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>update-uri</param-name>
        <param-value>/zkau</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet>
    <description>
    The asynchronous update engine for ZK</description>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.zkoss.zk.au.http.DHtmlUpdateServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zul</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>zkLoader</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.zhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>auEngine</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/zkau/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.zul</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

zk.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
    Created by ZK Studio
-->

<zk>

        <device-config>
            <device-type>ajax</device-type>
            <timeout-uri>/timeout.zul</timeout-uri><!-- An empty URL can cause the browser to reload the same URL -->
        </device-config>

    </zk>
```

LoginComposer.java

```
public class LoginComposer extends SelectorComposer<Component>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1657004425904043268L;

    @Wire
    private Button buttontestButton;

    @Listen("onClick = #testButton")
    public void cancelButton(){


             Executions.sendRedirect("/WEB-INF/zul/home.zul");


    }
}
```

Comment: Is your login page Spring controlled?

Comment: why do you want to place your zul directory under WEB-INF instead of WebContent ?

Comment: because it's common practice in java web development. It secures the pages from direct access. We use similar mechanism for jsps also. So I want to follow this practice.

Comment: If you really care about security, i guess it is better to use spring for auth and mapping/securing urls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### It is not possible

I looked around and found a german site tht explains, that the spec
of java-servlet define the WEB-INF folder as not client accessable,
cos it contains data as classes that never should be accessed from outside the server.

#### If you have the problems in a folder that is not WEB-INF:

You should better use [`Executions.sendRedirect(java.lang.String uri)`](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/latest/zk/org/zkoss/zk/ui/Executions.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)
to redirect by a button click with server-side action needed.
If you just want to redirect, set the buttons [href](http://www.zkoss.org/javadoc/6.5.1/zk/org/zkoss/zul/Button.html#setHref%28java.lang.String%29).
It should look like

```
Executions.sendRedirect("/zul/home.zul");
```

or
in java:

```
myButton.setHref("/zul/home.zul");
```

in zul:

```
<button ... href="/zul/home.zul" ...>
```

### Edit

I could write much, but the best would be to say, if you

1. do not use Spring follow [this](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/UI_Patterns/Forward_and_Redirect) and if you get 404
   check your deploy options/ deployed stuff.
2. use Spring, what I would prefer because of easy
   ajax login site, security annotations at java methods
   and easy zk integration, follow the [zk guide for spring](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Spring%20Essentials/Working%20with%20ZK%20Spring).

If you still have 404 and can't figure them out, please post your
configuration files or classes.

Comment: I had also tried that, but not working. My url changes to http://localhost:8080/abc/zul/home.zul and i get error in browser HTTP Status 404 - /zul/home.zul and description The requested resource (/zul/home.zul) is not available. remember both login and home pages are in zul under web-inf.

Comment: to forward the from index which is at webRoot, i am using following statement: <?forward uri="/WEB-INF/zul/login.zul"?>

Comment: I have added web.xml, zk.xml and LoginComposer.java files. Unfortunately I am still getting 404. I followed your previous guides.

Comment: The files look ok, so it seems to be a deployment problem. Check your deployment options and make a clean deployment. Means delet everything from the server and deploy. If you use eclipse, right click the server and click the both clean options you found there.

Comment: i did that but still the same error. May be zk doesn't support this feature and i have to use spring to do that. What do you say ???

Comment: I also tried a lot but doesn't get through. In jsp also response.sendRedirect() doesn't work but RequestDispatcher works fine... Still trying to solve this issue...

Comment: Thank you all @Nabil special thanks to you. so it's decided that spring is the way to do the job done.

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted direct/redirect access to pages under WEB-INF is not allowed by servlet specification, The best practice is to keep login.zul outside WEB-INF folder so users of application can have a direct access to it. Now for rest of the files you can keep them under WEB-INF folder and render them using include component or `Executions.createComponents()`.

Generally I keep my partial zul pages in WEB-INF folder so they aren't directly accessible but I keep my layout pages eg. home.zul or main.zul outside WEB-INF folder (also they should be restricted to access if user isn't logged in) Refer [here](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Spring_Essentials/Working_with_ZK_Spring/Working_with_ZK_Spring_Security/Add_Page_Based_Security_Using_Authorized_Roles) to learn how to restrict page access using Spring Security

Comment: you are also suggesting to use Spring. ZK doesn't have it's own facility to redirect file inside WEB-INF folder.

Comment: I suggested to use Spring Security to secure pages outside WEB-INF not for redirection. ZK doesn't have any facility to redirect file inside WEB-INF because it isn't allowed by Servlet specification. I don't believe even Spring can do that. Can you point to any resource/article that demonstrates Spring's feature that allows you to redirect to file under WEB-INF? I'm curious.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this help some one:

Forward zul file to another zul file you can use this code

```
<?forward uri="/directory_name/zul_fileName.zul"?>
```

For Include zul pages on same zul page you can use this code

```
<include src="/directory_name/zul_fileName.zul" > </include>
```

Answer (score -1):

**You cannot.**

Files in /WEB-INF folder are not directly accessible. If you want to have such kind of file system then you should better integrate spring framework.

Comment: Using Spring, does not counteract the security measures of the Servlet specification.